# Will behavioral issues occur in dogs that don't leave their mothers?

Tags: dogs, behavior, psychology, breeding

Information regarding separating puppies from their mothers, generally, only talks about at what age is it appropriate to remove a youngling from its dam.

There isn't much information about whether pups **need** to be parted from their mamas for behavioral reasons or not.

Will behavioral issues occur in dogs that don't leave their mothers?

Answer (score 1):

In most animals, that live social with each other (like cats and dogs) the nature added a built-in-health-system.

One part of this is, that individuals that are relatives should not have children together. (Children that get the same genetic material from mom and dad have a very high risk for illnesses).

In most cases this incest will be avoided by chasing the children off, when they are old enough to live alone. This behavior is nature-given (innate) to the parents and could not be trained off (as far as I know). In some cases the nature only wants to chase away the male children, in others both (male and female children).

Under these circumstances it could cause a lots of stress and aggression to the old dog and its child, if they need to stay close together.

Comment: Anecdotally, my family had both a mom and one of her daughters, and they were completely fine around each other. We got the mom after the daughter was an adult, though.

Comment: "A pack may be accepting of another wolf into their group if it is a distant relative, if reproduction rates are low due to loss or infertility of an alpha, or if their numbers are significantly reduced." from https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pack_(canine) I said, that stress/agression could be, not that it is a must be...